# Appearance of a tilde(~) in mac OSX terminal in the path

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, tilde

I am new to the Mac OSX environment, and was programming in C using the terminal. To change the current directory, I used the command `cd ..` to go one level up. However, this had a weird effect on the terminal. A clear screen on my mac terminal normally used to show this path always-

```
manishs-mbp:manishgiri$
```

However, since the time I did `cd ..` (to go one level up), the current pathway of the terminal has changed to:

```
manishs-mbp:~ manishgiri$
```

As you can see, there is a tilde now in the pathname. On reading about it, it looks like this tilde is used to represent the home directory in mac os. However, i would like to get rid of it, as it was earlier.

I tried to think of it, and realized that `cd ..` would have taken me one level up. So, I entered `pwd` in the terminal to see the current pathway(this is with the tilde situation), and got this-

```
manishs-mbp:~ manishgiri$ pwd
/Users/manishgiri
```

Maybe the tilde appears because I am now by default in the `/Users(Home)` folder. If that's the case, then how do I revert it back to the previous settings to get rid of the tilde?

Any help on this would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
PS1=`pwd `
```

to set your prompt.

If you like that, check in your home directory for a file called `.profile` and edit PS1 setting permanently into there.

[This](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) may help.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in answering. While I wasn't able to do precisely what I needed, following your link, I got to know that the bash shell on my mac(as with any other mac) is configured to show the current working directory basename. I used `echo $PS1` and understood that basically what I was looking to do was to remove `\W` from the resulting output `\h:\W \u\$`.

This involved permanently making a change of the `PS1` variable in the  shell's config file(`.bashrc`), and apparently it's not advisable for beginners(?), so I left it at that. But still, thanks a ton for the help!